# is there a way to iterate over an none type object in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, nonetype

I was solving python practice questions online when I came across this question which is not allowing me to iterate over the function arguments `a` and `b` in any way. I need to compare the `a[0]` and `b[0]`.

I've tried using generator, `iter` function, type conversions, but none of it seems to work:

```
def compareTriplets(a, b):

if __name__ == '__main__':
    fptr = open(os.environ['OUTPUT_PATH'], 'w')

    a = list(map(int, input().rstrip().split()))

    b = list(map(int, input().rstrip().split()))

    result = compareTriplets(a, b)

    fptr.write(' '.join(map(str, result)))
    fptr.write('\n')

    fptr.close()
```

The output is always `None type object is not iterable`.

Comment: what is the function body of `compareTriplets`? Right now, this will surely fail since the function doesn't even return anything.

Comment: thats what i have to code, the body of compare triplets. actually a is a sort of list with three values and so is b and i need to compare their values index wise but it wont allow me to iterate through a or b

Comment: Share full stack trace, where exactly in this code are you getting this error?

Comment: okay let me try out that one MrFuppes

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
File "Solution.py", line 25, in <module>
fptr.write(' '.join(map(str, result)))
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable

Comment: this is what i get every time, the above error

Comment: @jeetmistry added an answer, just to show you how this *could* work.

Comment: @jeetmistry: You need to provide a [MCVE]; the problem is in the body of `compareTriplets` (you likely forgot to return anything, at least along one code path), and you failed to provide it. Edit the code for it (and the traceback while you're at it) into your question.

Comment: Extremely minor side-note: `input` already strips the trailing newline, and `split` with no arguments implicitly strips leading and trailing whitespace anyway, so your `.rstrip()` calls are unnecessary.